# Firefox/Chrome: permanently set video playback volume

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, linux-mint

Problem: First video of a session starts at highest setting

System: Linux Mint, Firefox and Chrome

Suspected cause: I clear cookies when I close browsers

Q: (assuming it's cookies) what do do I enter in Firefox and Chrome settings to keep the volume setting cookie

Alibi: if it's not cookies, I'm open to other suggestions